# PDF/A Convertor .NET Component?

Tags: .net, pdf, pdfa

I am looking for a PDF/A Converter .NET Component or a way to make one what all technologies of components should be used? Ii would take a word document as as stream and convert it into pdf etc.

Convert word (2003/2007 mostly..and if other office formats etc it would be good.

Convert not create.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Http://www.activepdf.com/](http://www.activepdf.com/)

Answer (score 2):

## Several options

- [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/pdf-component.aspx) - Expensive
- [Textcontrol](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/products/dotnetserverwpf/overview/) - Very expensive
- [Spire](http://e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html) - $800
- [Raster Edge](http://www.rasteredge.com/dotnet-imaging/addon-pdf-document-generator/) - Very expensive
- [Gembox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) - $480
- [Subsystems](http://www.subsystems.com/dpw.htm) - $550
- [Muhimbi](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services.aspx) - Expensive and uses Office interop
- [ActivePDF](http://www.activepdf.com/index.php/products/docconverter) - $400. I think they use Office interop on the server
- Office Interop - Free, but [not supported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) by M$ and ... just don't.
- Open Office Interop - Also free. Also scary.

Prices in US$ are current as of January, 2014

#### What is this interop of which you speak?

Where you install Word or something on the server, include the DLL in your project as a reference and then call methods.  Problem is these libraries were not written for multi-user/server/web environments. Almost 100% guaranteed to give you errors.

Comment: Muhimbi seemed to be best.You need office installed on the server to guarantee conversion of word documents to PDF are 100% What you see is what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look into [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Two questions come to mind:

1. What is the business case/quantity of Office documents you are translating? Is this a web app that will have hundreds of thousands of users hitting the web server simultaneously, or are you OK with a batch style or to throttle the number of users?
2. What level of quality do you want the PDF at? Print-quality, or web?

Comment: 1.Workflow related;document(mostly word) needs to be converted to pdf for applying digital signature.
2.Print or web legible i.e

Comment: ActivePDF is a good product, but I believe default is to use the Office back-engine, which means it is limited to instances of office run on the machine. Ghostscript is a great multi-threaded product and is opensource, but it can only handle postscript to PDF, so users would need to generate their own PS files through a print driver. 

My experience with Office to PDF has been less than fun (especially dealing with proprietary MS formats), so I'd recommend taking a step back and determining if you really need Office to PDF.

Comment: When generating PDFs, often applications will spawn an instance of Office to generate postscript files. You'll note that ActivePDF requires Office -- "Microsoft Office 2007, if converting Microsoft Office files. (This is the recommended configuration for processing Office files.)" at http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/docconverter2009/sysreqs.cfm  Problem is Office 2007 isn't really meant to be multi-threaded, so you may run into concurrency issues if you go  this route.